# Реализация приложения-информационной системы, паттерн репозиторий

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, repository, сопоставление-с-образцом

Мне нужно создать репозиторий для работы с данными, вариант задания такой: инженер, персона, главный инженер, рабочая группа. Данные загружаются из xml, json или csv. Сохранение тоже в виде файла одного из этих форматов.

Помогите понять структуру программы, пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю, как это организовать.

1. Для каждого формата отдельный класс репозиторий, которые наследуются от interface IRepository?
2. Инженер и главный инженер наследуются от персоны? Тогда группа - это класс с полями, например, "номер группы" и List, и мне нужно создать TeamRepository, чтобы сортировать, фильтровать, добавлять данные по группе рабочих и PersonRepository, чтобы добавлять студентов?

Простите, если вопросы очень тривиальные, только учусь и правда хочу понять!